# Python jinja2 filter to find hosts matching a group in ansible

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

I have a need to search for ansible inventory in the current play by group type and grabbing an arbitrary number of them.

I mostly want advice on if the _first_run variable is the best way to handle this inspection. I put it there so that a key error doesn't occur during the iterable creation.

Also, I'm unfamiliar with iterator speed in the real world. Is there any speed gain by putting the generator outside of the main function?

If you are unfamiliar with ansible's hostvars it is a dictionary of all the inventory. Each piece of inventory has the full list of groups so I can grab any arbitrary one.

I realize with strict inputs I could make this much simpler. I just wanted review on a situation where I had to support either input.

```
# This is what the top level input can be. In retrospect I could just
# force users to send me the full hostvars dictionary and simplify this
# and not accept arbitrary hosts (in this case 'a host'/'b host'.
# {'hostvars': {'a host': 'groups': {<the keys in here are what I want>}
#               'b host': 'groups': {<identical keys to the above>}
# }


def hosts_in_group(hostvars, active_hosts, group):
    """
    Return an iterable of all the hosts in a group.

    Example use case:
        Want a single host in group linux from the hosts in the current play ('ansible_play_hosts')
    Example usage:
        {{ hostvars|hosts_in_group(ansible_play_hosts, 'linux')|first }}

    :param hostvars: The full hostvars dictionary
    :param active_hosts: List of hosts to search. ex. ansible_play_hosts
    :param group: Group name to search ex. 'linux'
    :return: iterable of matching hosts
    """
    for hostname in hostvars.keys():
        hostvar = hostvars[hostname]
        break
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("No inventory found. Was hostvars the argument? Do you have inventory defined?")

    for host in active_hosts:
        if host in hostvar['groups'][group]:
            yield host


def _hosts_group_iterable(vars, active_hosts, group):
    """Iterable for hosts_in_group"""
    for host in active_hosts:
        if host in vars['groups'][group]:
            yield host


class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'hosts_in_group': hosts_in_group,
        }
```

Comment: Why was this edited? It fundamentally changed my question. Several of the things that I asked for help for are no longer even in the code. I was asking for review of how I handled that potential issue, not on whether handling the issue in that way was objectively best.